# WPF - ReactiveUI InvokeCommand not working

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to learn ReactiveUI so I'm making example app, but I'm having problem with `InvokeCommand`. Basically every time `SearchPhrase` property is changed my `ShowSearchPhraseCommand` should be invoked.

Here is my View:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" >


    <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" 
     Text="{Binding Path=SearchPhrase, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ReactiveCommand ShowSearchPhraseCommand { get; private set; }

string _searchPhrase;
public string SearchPhrase
{
    get { return _searchPhrase; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _searchPhrase, value); }
}

public SecondViewModel(IScreen hostScreen)
{
    HostScreen = hostScreen;

    // Commands
    ShowSearchPhraseCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => ShowSearchPhraseCommandHandler(SearchPhrase));

    // WhenAny
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchPhrase).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).InvokeCommand(ShowSearchPhraseCommand);
}

private void ShowSearchPhraseCommandHandler(string searchPhrase)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Phrase: {searchPhrase}");
}
```

And here is my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command expects a `Unit`:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchPhrase)
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .Select(_ => System.Reactive.Unit.Default) //<--
    .InvokeCommand(ShowSearchPhraseCommand);
```

...unless you define it as a `ReactiveCommand<string, Unit>`:

```
public ReactiveCommand<string, System.Reactive.Unit> ShowSearchPhraseCommand { get; private set; }
...
ShowSearchPhraseCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<string>(ShowSearchPhraseCommandHandler);
```